# How to return a Filter iterator filtering by struct members

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a Tic-Tac-Toe game on the console. For one method of my `Board` struct, I'd like to return all positions of a certain type.

```rust
type PlayerID = i32;
type Position = (usize, usize);

#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum TileState {
    Player(PlayerID),
    None,
}

pub struct Board {
    board: [[TileState; 3]; 3],
}

impl Board {
    const ALL_POSITIONS: [Position; 3] = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)];

    pub fn free_tiles<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Position> + 'a {
        Board::ALL_POSITIONS
            .iter()
            .filter(|(x, y)| self.board[*x][*y] == TileState::None)
            .cloned()
    }
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `self`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/lib.rs:20:21
   |
20 |             .filter(|(x, y)| self.board[*x][*y] == TileState::None)
   |                     ^^^^^^^^ ---- `self` is borrowed here
   |                     |
   |                     may outlive borrowed value `self`
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/lib.rs:18:9
   |
18 | /         Board::ALL_POSITIONS
19 | |             .iter()
20 | |             .filter(|(x, y)| self.board[*x][*y] == TileState::None)
21 | |             .cloned()
   | |_____________________^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `self` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
20 |             .filter(move |(x, y)| self.board[*x][*y] == TileState::None)
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Preferably, I'd like to avoid having to copy `ALL_POSITIONS`, `self.board` or create a new array in any other way.
What would be the best Rust style to solve this problem?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c72d5160479035d9d20efdd7ae78df47 will do what you want I guess.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would copy `self.board` (or maybe even move it?) which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. If it does take ownership of self.board, that would make the Board object unusable unless I am missing something.

Comment: `&'a self` is a reference and your structure doesn't implement copy, this just borrow self so reference so it's doesn't copy, it's take the ownership of the reference to self

Comment: Now that you've completely rewritten your code such that it produces a different error from the original question, please update the title to match the question you are now asking.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is very helpful, but why not just return a collection of positions instead of an Iterator?